# Why don't mouse events work in Windows terminals using ConHost?

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, xterm, conhost

I was wondering why mouse events don't seem to work on Windows for most terminals while using OpenSSH. Let me explain.

Let's say you're using `tmux` in WSL, via `cmd.exe`. Mouse events, last time I checked, work perfectly fine on every terminal for that case. All or most terminals on Windows use Conhost under the hood somewhere.

However, let's say that I have a Linux virtual machine running on my computer and I'm SSH'd into it using the standard OpenSSH client that comes with windows.  SSH works fine for the most part, but Mouse events in the remote `tmux` do not.

The only terminal that I've found on Windows that supports mouse events even while in SSH is **MinTTY**. I use MinTTY from the *Git for Windows* install as a daily driver, and it works great albeit being a little bit laggy. All the emojis are displayed fine, and all or most mouse events are supported just fine.

I know Git for Windows uses OpenSSH now (since they give you that option while installing), so I don't think it's an OpenSSH issue.
Rather, I think it's an issue with Terminal emulation and/or Conhost, but I wanted to get the lowdown from someone who's more versed in Windows terminals and Terminal emulation than I am. I don't think MinTTY uses Conhost, unless I'm wrong. Is this a matter of `xterm` emulation?

Thanks!

Comment: Any example of mouse events that does not work? mintty also uses conhost, it's everywhere!!

Comment: @Biswapriyo that might mean then that MinTTY applies additional xterm emulation on top of ConHost. The examples that I gave are the first thing that come to mind; I haven't tried it on all Windows terminals, but mouse events don't work on any of them in SSH.